# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails?

Tags: mysql

**Item**     - ItemID(PRI), ItemName, Price,Qty 
                                   **Invoice**  - InvoiceID(PRI), Description(PRI), Item_ItemID(FK), Qty, Price

Relationship : one-to-many non-identifying relationship (Item.ItemID & Invoice.Item_ItemID)

ItemID is the PRIMARY KEY of Item table.
InvoiceID & Description is the PRIMARY KEY of Invoice table
(COMPOSITE PRIMARY KEY).
I can INSERT ItemID to Invoice table that include in the ItemTable but when  I'm trying to INSERT different ItemID it gives this ERROR...
" Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails  " ?????

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour.

A foreign key constraint stops you from entering an item-id into the invoice-table that does not already exist in the item-table. That's what a foreign key constraint *IS*.

Here's a link to the [mysql foreign key docs for more info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: Thank you !!!! 
But this is a non-identifying relationship so I thought I can insert itemID that not in the Item table